# Django ForeignKey, hide from user select options in dropdown menu

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, foreign-keys

I have standard Django models with ForeignKey.

Django docs:

"ForeignKey is represented by django.forms.ModelChoiceField, which is a ChoiceField whose choices are a model QuerySet."

and

"If the model field has choices set, then the form field’s widget will be set to Select, with choices coming from the model field’s choices."

Now I have dropdown menu with choices.

I don't want dropdown menu where user can see options. I want CharField(textfield or similar) where user type, but still
that must be one of the options from the database for that field. He must type a valid entry.

I tried:

```
class TransakcijeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = models.Transakcije
    fields = .....
    labels = .....
    widgets ={'subscriber':forms.TextInput()}
```

but I receive the message:

"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."
(entry is correct and it works with dropdown menu)

This is my first question here and I'm sorry if I miss the form.

Comment: If you don't mind explaining, why is it that you don't want to use a selection box for this form? Trying to make it be a text box, if it is possible to do, would mean that the user would have to know the possible entries in the database.

Comment: It's users identification, 16 digits number. Third party enters this number via barcode or manually. It's not good practice that third party can see all valid users id codes.

Comment: I can post an answer that should work, but you will likely have to adjust it for specifics of how your models are defined in your project.

Comment: Please do it. I will adjust it for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because your form is still treating the `subscriber` field as a `ModelChoiceField` because you are only overriding what widget is rendered to html. You need to change the actual field type of your field. You can define your form like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class TransakcijeForm(forms.ModelForm):
   subscriber = forms.CharField()
   class Meta:
      model = models.Transakcije
      fields = ....
      labels = ....
   
   def clean_subscriber(self):
      subscriber_id = self.cleaned_data['subscriber']
      try:
         # adjust this line to appropriately get the model object that you need
         subscriber = SubscriberModel.objects.get(id=subscriber_id)
         return subscriber
      except:
         raise ValidationError('Subscriber does not exist')
```

The line `subscriber = forms.CharField()` will change the form to treat the field as a `CharField` rather than a `ModelChoiceField`. Doing this will cause the form to return the `subscriber` field value as a string, so you will need to get the appropriate model object based on the value of the field. That is what the `clean_subscriber(self)` function is for. It needs to be named like `clean_<field name>()`. That function will take the string that is returned by the form, try and find the correct model object and return it if an object is found. If it finds no matching objects it will raise a `ValidationError` so the form doesn't submit with a bad value.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and answer here. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, let me know if you have any questions or how it works.

Comment: Great! It works! I adjust this to my project and solve the problem. This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with the rest of your project.